# How to handle c# exceptions in PLINQ query on EnumeratFiles or EnumeratFolders

Tags: c#, linq, exception

I came across some nice posts to get a total count of files and/or folders using the code below:

```
  DirectoryInfo dirInfo = new DirectoryInfo(myBaseDirectory + @"\");
          var count = await Task.FromResult(dirInfo.EnumerateDirectories()
                   .AsParallel()
                   .SelectMany(di => di.EnumerateFiles("*.*", SearchOption.AllDirectories))
                   .Count() + dirInfo.EnumerateFiles("*.*", SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly).Count());
```

This works great. Until I tried to access a NTFS formatted drive. Then an exception is thrown on the EnumerateFiles function. This is an UnauthorizedAccessException on the volume information folder.

Now my question is, how can I rewrite this code in such a way that when exceptions are thrown, the codes keeps "looping". In other words, it just skips the files or folders that throw an exception.

I try-catch around the whole code doesn't work. As far as I understand now I should put a try-catch in the selectMany-part. Something like:

```
.SelectMany(di => { try { di.EnumerateFiles("*.*", SearchOption.AllDirectories); } catch{ }})
```

but then the code doesn't compile. Any suggestions?

Comment: what is the compiler error? apart from being awfully slow, it should work. there is no rule that would prevent a try...catch in the body of a lambda function.

Comment: The try...catch construction doesn't return anything and is therefor invalid for the SelectMany. Try putting `return` before the `di.EnumerateFiles` and return an empty enumeration inside the catch (you might also explicitly catch the `UnauthorizedAccessException` only to still throw other unexpected errors)

Comment: Are you sure that going parallel actually improves performance here? At a guess, I'd venture that this increases disk-thrashing and actually slows down performance. You can issue many simultaneous IO requests, but you still only have one hard-drive that runs **much** slower than even a single, synchronous thread.

Comment: @dlatikay what would you suggest if it slows down that much?

Comment: @Me.Name I wil give it a try. Thx

Comment: @spender I don't have to worry about that too much (for now ;-))

Comment: I wonder, what is the point of `await Task.FromResult(...)`, what is your intention?

Comment: Inside your SelectMany you will have to return a result. You don't do that, hence the error. See the answer

Comment: If `EnumerateFiles` throws an exception for one file, does that mean the enumeration stops and will not return any further files?  I don't know how you would get access to the other files if that is the case.

Comment: as I understood it fails on a per-directory basis, when the directory is on an NTFS volume. so attempting to enumerate more is not necessary, as long as we're sure the exception is not due to a single file. which may be difficult to detect reliably.

Comment: @JamesFaix correct. It just stops.

Comment: @PeterBons I use the await because it is an async function. With dlatikay's solution, it works now

Comment: await Task.FromResult(...) does not make anything async. It is a delusion to give you a false sense that it is. It create a task with the result already set. Just remove it and it will still function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short lambda syntax (which implies the expression value of its only statement as the return value) cannot be used when there is a block statement like try..catch inside ([more here](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/7df3b32a-5a7f-4509-8cf2-8954962912d9/lamda-expression-return-statement-question?forum=csharplanguage)).
In your case, you need to use the `return` statement to indicate which expression is the result of the lambda function:

```
SelectMany(di => { 
    try 
    { 
        return di.EnumerateFiles("*.*", SearchOption.AllDirectories); 
    } 
    catch 
    { 
        /* just skip */
        return new FileInfo[] { };
    }
})
```

Comment: That did it. Thank you. It is the same solutions as Me.name. No performance issues so far